# Does GAE Datastore support 'partial text search'?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm very beginner.

I want to make a information management system using Go language on Google App Engine.
Users will create, edit, delete and search entities.

I have navigated GAE site, but could not find 'partial text search' on Datastore.
Partial text search, I mean, search entities contain 'partial text' entered.

Or, can you give me a tip to make such a system. (for free)

Very Sorry for low-grade question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the datastore, you need to use the full-text search API. Unfortunately, that is not yet available with Go: apparently the best way to use it is to set up a module in your app that uses Python2.7, and exposes the search functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You make me feel easy.