# GAE Search API Now support Partial Searching

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search

Since the Fall update, GAE now supports partial searching. Per the documentation: "The API supports partial text matching on string fields".

This seems to be a very popular request,  per many threads:
[Partial matching GAE search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899083/partial-matching-gae-search-api)
[Does GAE Datastore support 'partial text search'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377152/does-gae-datastore-support-partial-text-search)

So I would assume a search for 'pyt' would now return 'python'

Has anyone gotten this to work? Doesn't work for me.  I'm curious if there's some setting required, like the ~ for stemming.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer ? I am experiencing the same problem, everything set up, but is only responding to full matches.

Comment: Never did get a response.  I'm still curious what "Partial Matching" means to Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The API supports partial text matching on string fields" in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/ refers to matching **by tokens**.  Specifically, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Tokenizing_string_fields ...:

> The string is split into tokens wherever whitespace or special
>   characters (punctuation marks, hash sign, etc.) appear. The index will
>   include an entry for each token. This enables you to search for
>   keywords and phrases comprising only part of a field's value.

Therefore your assumption:

> So I would assume a search for 'pyt' would now return 'python'

is ill-founded -- "partial search" means parts of a **document** (a subset of the **tokens** in a text field thereof), *not* parts of **each token** (that would cause a combinatorial explosion, e.g the single token `python` would have to be indexed as each and every one of the entries:

```
p
py
pyt
pyth
pytho
python
y
yt
yth
ytho
ython
t
th
tho
thon
h
ho
hon
o
on
n
```

If you **want** that, it's easy enough to write your own code to produce the explosion (producing a pseudo-document with all of these substrings from a real starting document) -- but, for any non-trivial starting document, you may easily end up either paying for a ridiculous amount of resources, or hitting a hard ceiling of absolute maximum quotas.

Hint: if you do a web search for "pyt", do you find docs containing "python"?  Try -- the former gives 10 million hits (Peninsula Youth Theater, Michael Jackson's P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing), etc etc), the latter, 180 million hits (the language, the snake, the comedy group:-).